# chrome opens wonderlands link on scrolling

Tags: android, google-chrome, virus

I have been seeing this problem for a long time in my android mobile devices and laptop chrome browser.

When i try to scroll down a page, browse just hangs for a micro second and then automatically opens a link (wonderlands..... .php)

This wonderlands tab has random ads in case of laptop and in case of mobile it says virus detected!

Any body has any idea how to deal with this??

P.S.:- I googled about overcoming this but did not find any related problem. So i am curious to know wheteher this issue is related to my Google account and spreads itself on devices where i open my google account or is this a google bug/some sort of virus?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. You can try asking on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) but you probably need to better word the question.

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://superuser.com/questions/1016679/wonderlands-com-annoying-pops-up-none-stop-on-google-chrome-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Trix:- I want to add that i am getting this problem majorly on Android phone. I know many of the problems are solved by un-install and re-install of OS but i dont think that this is the best solution and i go for this only in the extreme cases (this does not seem to be an extreme case for now ).. have tried reinstalling chrome on phone though, no luck..

Answer (score 0):

First try to open the chrome browser in Incognito mode . Yo can do it by
Ctrl+Shift+N. 
Open any page you wish to open and check if problem persist.

If problem is not in incognito mode  then try to find any suspicious  extensions by typing(where you write URL)

```
 chrome://extensions/
```

Comment: Incognito window and extension removal does not help..
I have observed that if the page has not yet loaded and i start scrolling the page, then this problem happens!

But i have not found any proper way to overcome this!